# How to escape SECRET_KEY in Django from environment file when generated SECRET_KEY begins with '$'?

Tags: python, django, environment-variables, django-settings

In my Django project I have a `.env` file that contains the `SECRET_KEY` for the production settings.

I generated the secret key by running a script from the command line (Here it just prints the generated key as an example).

```sh
python -c 'from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key; print(get_random_secret_key())'
```

It just so happens that a secret key was generated that started with a `'$'` character.

My `.env` file looked like this.

```
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=$*%0e@-7suq*h#2(srya8n&lhb(qy+73xj_db)tpq4qenknk2%
```

This is read in my production settings file  in the following way

```py
import os
import environ

env = environ.Env()

# BASE_DIR is the root level directory of the project
env_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env')
if os.path.exists(env_file):
    environ.Env.read_env(env_file=env_file) # reading .env file

SECRET_KEY = env('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')
```

When I run my Django project with this secret key I get the following error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the *%0e@-7suq*h#2(srya8n&lhb(qy+73xj_db)tpq4qenknk2% environment variable
```

Because of the `'$'` character Django seems to think that the secret key value is an environment variable itself. This is understandable as environment variables in Bash have a `'$'` prefix.

But when I try changing the .env file to

```
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY='$*%0e@-7suq*h#2(srya8n&lhb(qy+73xj_db)tpq4qenknk2%'
```

or

```
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY="$*%0e@-7suq*h#2(srya8n&lhb(qy+73xj_db)tpq4qenknk2%"
```

I get the same error.

#### How do I escape the SECRET_KEY in an .env file on the off chance a secret key is generated with a leading `'$'` (that works in DJango using my production settings code)?

django version: 3.0.3

django-environ version: 0.4.5

Answer (score 0):

This article [here](https://dev.to/vladyslavnua/how-to-protect-your-django-secret-and-oauth-keys-53fl) suggest to use pip to install `dotenv` and completely simplified the process of hiding the secret key. At least for beginners.

Comment: Given that `dotenv` works it appears to be an issue with the django-environ package. I will be using `dotenv` moving forward. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two ways to solve this problem.

The first is to be explcit about what is in your `.env` file, using `django_environ`:

```
#.env
SECRET_KEY=(str, '$*%0e@-7suq*h#2(srya8n&lhb(qy+73xj_db)tpq4qenknk2%')
```

The other is to do as is indicated in the article linked to above (https://dev.to/vladyslavnua/how-to-protect-your-django-secret-and-oauth-keys-53fl), which effectively suggests that the same issue is present in `django_environ` and `dotenv`.

When retrieving the `.env` value (using `dotenv`):

```
#settings.py
SECRET_KEY = str(os.getenv('SECRET_KEY'))
```

In both cases you are explicitly indicating to django that the values retrieved are strings. You could potentially run into other issues like this, and need to be explicit about the data type returned:

```
#.env
DEBUG=(bool, True)
SOME_INT=(int, 1)
…
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i found a work around.

Remove the `$` symbol from your `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY` at **.env** file:

```
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY='*%0e@-7suq*h#2(srya8n&lhb(qy+73xj_db)tpq4qenknk2%'
```

and add it to your **settings.py**

```
SECRET_KEY = f"${env('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')}"
```